# While loop for a raw_input gives strange output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, while-loop

No mather what input I give I get the output "I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here."
Like if I input 17 I get "I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here." and if I input 18-59 I get "I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here."

```
while True:
    age = raw_input("\n So tell me " + str(name) + ", how old are you?: ")
    if age.isdigit() == False:
        print "\n Please, put only in numbers!"
        time.sleep(3)
    elif age < 18:
        print "\n %s. A minor. You got to be atleast 18 to go on this adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
        time.sleep(7)
        exit(0) 
    elif age >= 60:
        print "\n %s. I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
        time.sleep(5)
        exit(0)
    else:
        print "\n %s. You're starting to get old." % age
        break
```

Comment: `raw_input` gives you a string, every time, so you can't compare it to numbers. Try `int(raw_input(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `raw_input` always returns a string object, and those don't really compare to `int` types. You need to do some type conversion.

If you want to use `isdigit` to test if the input is a number, then you should proceed this way:

```
while True:
    age = raw_input("\n So tell me " + str(name) + ", how old are you?: ")
    if age.isdigit() == False:
        print "\n Please, put only in numbers!"
        time.sleep(3)
    elif int(age) < 18:
        print "\n %s. A minor. You got to be atleast 18 to go on this adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
        time.sleep(7)
        exit(0) 
    elif int(age) >= 60:
        print "\n %s. I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
        time.sleep(5)
        exit(0)
    else:
        print "\n %s. You're starting to get old." % age
        break
```

However, you can simplify the code a little by converting to an integer right away, and just catching the exception if it's an invalid string:

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(raw_input("\n So tell me " + str(name) + ", how old are you?: "))
        if age < 18:
            print "\n %s. A minor. You got to be atleast 18 to go on this adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
            time.sleep(7)
            exit(0) 
        elif age >= 60:
            print "\n %s. I think you're to old to go on an adventure. Your adventure ends here." % age
            time.sleep(5)
            exit(0)
        else:
            print "\n %s. You're starting to get old." % age
            break
    except ValueError:
        print "\n Please, put only in numbers!"
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect with the `try` and `except` exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare your input as an `int`

```
age = int(raw_input("\n So tell me " + str(name) + ", how old are you?: "))
```

Otherwise you are comparing a `str` to an `int`. See the following example

```
>>> 5 < 10
True
>>> type(5)
<type 'int'>

>>> '5' < 10
False
>>> type('5')
<type 'str'>
```

In Python 2.x, comparing values of different types generally ignores the values and compares the types instead. Because `str >= int`, any string is `>=` any integer. In Python 3.x you get a `TypeError` instead of silently doing something confusing and hard to debug.

Comment: One problem: he's checking `age.isdigit`, so this is too early to convert it to `int`. You either need to move the conversion into an `else` clause under that first `if`, or use a `try`/`except` instead of an `if`, or otherwise restructure things in some way.

Comment: That gives me a  'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
Is it because 'isdigit' only works with strings?

Comment: Correct. If you try to cast a `str` to an `int` that contains letters, for example, you will get a `ValueError`. So you could check for digits first before trying to cast.

Comment: In that case, try testing on `elif int(age) < 18` and `elif int(age) >= 60`.

Comment: That still gives me 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: @MarkusLindberg: The `try` statement is probably the most Pythonic way to write this. But as I said in my first comment, there are multiple ways to do this.